# Divide all element of a vector (with 9 elements) by first, second, ...hundredth element from another vector (with 100 elements)

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, apply

Hello I really need help with my program in R. I have vector with nine elements and I need divide each element by first, second, ...., hundredth, element from another vector. I try this for loop but it didn't works

```
er=matrix(1,100)
LCZ2016=matrix(1,100)

for(i in 2:100)
  for(j in 1:9)
  {
    {
      er[i]=rnorm(1, 0, SdeLcCZ2016)
      LCZ2016[i]=DEA['L'][CZ2016,][j,]/exp(er[i])
    } 
  }
```

the =DEA['L'][CZ2016,] is vector with 9 elements and I need create LCZ2016 with 100 elements like this

```
LCZ2016[1]=DEA['L'][CZ2016,][1] //exp(er[1])
LCZ2016[2]=DEA['L'][CZ2016,][2] //exp(er[2])
.
.
.
LCZ2016[50]=DEA['L'][CZ2016,][1] //exp(er[50])
```

etc.
Please do you have any idea ?

Comment: This should be possible. But please provide a _minimal_ [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
a <- 1:9
b <- 1:100 

output = sapply(a, function(x) x/b)
print(dim(output))

[1] 100   9
```

Also, you can do as suggested by @Andre

```
sapply(a, /, b)
```

Comment: did you mean `sapply(a, `/`, b)` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `outer` is meant for.

```
a <- 1:9
b <- 1:100 
out2 <- outer(a, b, '/')
dim(out2)
#[1]   9 100
```

Compare with [YOLO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691947/r-devide-all-element-of-a-vector-with-9-elements-by-first-second-hundre/53691992#53691992).

```
output <- sapply(a, function(x) x/b)

identical(t(out2), output)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @markus Not deliberate, I've messed up the mouse clicks.